# Lightning Datatable with custom validation

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation, slds

I have a Lightning Datatable to which I want to add custom validation for inline editing.

Currently I have this following:

```
        <lightning-datatable 
            key-field="rowId"
            data={seniorityData}
            columns={columns}
            errors={errors}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            oncellchange={handleCellChange}
            suppress-bottom-bar
            hide-checkbox-column>
```

Where handleCellChange carries out validation on the draft value and populates errors accordingly.
But the errors look like this:

[image: Validation Errors]

I want to know if it is possible to style the error messages to be consistent with [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#Required-form-element-with-error). It seems that those validation rules and error messages are hard-coded - is there any way to create custom validation rules and error messages apart from the errors attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that enters the "you'll have to write your own component" territory. While SLDS is the ideal form, whatever's in Salesforce is what we get. Note that if this has changed recently (in the last six months or so) in SLDS, there's always a chance it'll get updated in Salesforce later; there is some lag time between SLDS changes and implementation in Salesforce, since SLDS drives the design for Salesforce components. If you don't want to make the considerable effort to create your own component, but want the SLDS design, you might want to contact someone at Salesforce that would know what the roadmap looks like to see if this is on the table or not.